# Trigger asp.net event on complete jquery file upload

Tags: jquery, asp.net, file, upload

I'm using jquery file upload to upload images to asp.net server (http://www.webtrendset.com/2011/06/22/complete-code-example-for-using-blueimp-jquery-file-upload-control-in-asp-net/)

I need to trigger an asp.net event (or click a hidden asp.net button) when the file upload is complete. I try to add code to the done function but I dont get it to work.

Button can not be reached...

```
 done: function (e, data) {
 document.getElementById('<%=Button1.ClientID%>').click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is done function triggered? you can use jquery to click your button like;

```
$('input[id$=Button1]').click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing this to execute the postback event with javascript:

```
__doPostBack('<%= Button1.ClientID  %>', '');
```

I would also recommend using ClientIDMode = static in your web.config so you don't have to programmatically determine the ID of your element.